# Infinite linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, systems-of-equations, matrix-calculus

I have to solve this system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-R x_0 + w_1 x_1 + v_2 x_2 = 0 \\
R x_0 -(v_1 + w_1 + R) x_1 + w_2 x_2 + v_3 x_3 = 0\\
\vdots \\
R x_{i-1} -(v_i + w_i + R) x_i + w_{i+1} x_{i+1} + v_{i+2} x_{i+2} = 0\\
\vdots \\
\end{cases}
\label{system_stat_stat}
\end{equation}

where $R$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are parameters and ( $x_i$; $i\geq 0$ ) an infinite vector
$$\begin{cases}
v_i=\beta i (i-1) \\
w_i=\gamma i \\
q_i = -R-v_i-w_i
\end{cases}
$$
Actually I'm working with probability distributions. We have one more equation due to the normalization, $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i = 1$.

Does anyone recognize the problem with a similar one?
there exist a closed (not recursive) analytical solution of this system ($x_i=f(i,R,\beta,\gamma)$)? if yes, how can I get it?
also a reference about this kind of problem would be helpful.
thanks a lot in advice.

more info:
The matrix representation of the system is the following pentadiagonal
$$
\bar{x}P = (x_0, x_1, \dots, x_i,\dots)
\begin{pmatrix}
    -R & R & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots \\
    w_{1} & q_1 & R & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots \\
    v_2 & w_{2} & q_2 & R & \dots & 0 & \dots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & R & \dots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & v_i & w_{i} &  q_i & \dots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\
\end{pmatrix}
=0
$$
where $q_i = - w_i - v_i - R$